# Drop down list error

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have code where I have to display the content of my database. I have a drop down list for gender.  If the user chooses either of the gender it will display the records with the same value in what they choose. The result is in table form:

This is my code.

```
    <html>
        <h1> Student Search </h1>

            <body>
                <table border="1" width="500">
                    <form name="StudentSearch" action="search.php" method="get">

                <table border="1">
                <h3> Filter </h3>
                <h3> Gender </h3>
                    <select name="gender">
                    <option value="">. . .</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option><br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                    </select>
                </table>

    <br/ >
    <br/ >
    <br/ >
    <br/ >
                    <h3> Result </h3>
                <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th> Lastname </th>
                    <th> Firstname </th>
                    <th> Middlename </th>
                    <th> Gender </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

                        mysql_select_db("PUP") or die(mysql_error());  

                        $strSQL = "SELECT lastname, firstname, middlename, gender FROM people WHERE gender=" . $_GET["gender"];
                        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

                        $i = 1;
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                        echo "<dt> </dt><dd>" . si . " " . $row["lastname"] . " " . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["middlename"] . " " . $row["gender"] . "</dd>"; 
                        $i++;
                        }
                    ?>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table> 
                </table>

            </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is actually the exact problem? "if they choose either of the gender it will display the records with the same value in what they choose." sounds like everything works as expected - am I wrong in reading that as "when selecting a gender, you see people of that gender"? Would be great to have an example of the output you get and what you actually expect.

Comment: Yeah, when someone select a gender it will display the records of people of that gender. In my code it display nothing. What I expected to see is a table that has a columns of lastname, firtsname, middle name and gender. Thanks.

Comment: Would have helped greatly if you had stated in the question that it shows nothing! As Prasad Rajapaksha already suggested below, try executing "echo $strSQL;", just before the mysql_query call!

Comment: I already do that it just display my query in just one columns then the rest is null. I already do some stuff like fetch_array, I also do some looping but it didn't work.

Comment: And what is your query, have you tried executing it directly on the database? like with phpmyadmin? Please show some effort, that same thing was already asked in another comment as well...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<select name="gender">
                <option value="">. . .</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option><br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                </select>
```

To

```
<select name="gender">
                <option value="">. . .</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                </select>
                <br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Because you were closing the  to late, you had some `<br />` and a submit button inside it, which is no valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues.

1. HTML  button is inside the  selection. First make it out.
2. I think bellow line need to be modified as.

   $strSQL = "SELECT lastname, firstname, middlename, gender FROM people WHERE gender='" . $_GET["gender"] . "'";

Cheers.

Prasad

Comment: The code still have an error. It does not display the result. I will get the data at my database and put it in a table. Like this: | Lastname | firstname| | middelname | gender | ....values..... | gervacio | jeneca | parales | female | .... it will display respectively....

Comment: OK great.  Put " echo $strSQL; " before the line " $rs = mysql_query($strSQL); " and copy the query. Execute it on a MySQL client tool. See whether you got expected result there.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you're producing is not valid; try running a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) on it.
The following section has the problem that line breaks are not allowed inside a select, and also not a submit:

```
<select name="gender">
 <option value="">. . .</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 <option value="Male">Male</option><br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</select>
```

you should rewrite this to

```
<select name="gender">
 <option value="">. . .</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
</select>
<br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

It's also not valid to have content directly inside a table, like you're doing here:

```
<table border="1">
<h3> Filter </h3>
<!-- ...other stuff -->
</table>
```

You'd have to open a table row and cell first, like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3> Filter </h3>
      <!-- ...other stuff -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The validator should tell you all this, and more.

Comment: is there anything wrong wit my php code? it still didn't display the result?

Comment: @akien_ghie09: We would have to know a bit more (e.g. table structure, what the expected result is) to say anything about that! what is for example the type of gender column?

Comment: Ahhm. I would like to get th data from my database and display it in a table form. Like this: | Lastname | firstname| | middelname | gender | ....it will display..... | gervacio | jeneca | parales | female | .... respectively... its like before it can display the result i have to choose first what is the gender then after that it will display all the records that is female if ever i choose female and male if i choose male.

Comment: good to know, but what do you currently get? and it would be great if you could update your question with these things (you can edit the question!). That way it's immediately clear what you need without having to read all comments